# What are Mutation Class Quirks?

Tags: my-hero-academia

In one Boku no Hero Academia Wikia [Wikia](http://bokunoheroacademia.wikia.com/wiki/Shota_Aizawa) they mention Shota Aizawa can't erase Mutation-Class Quirks. Which are these Quirks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mutation type quirks tend to be irregular body quirks.
Think of [Toru Hagakure's transparency quirk](http://bokunoheroacademia.wikia.com/wiki/Transparency)
.

> Mutant (異形 Igyō?)-type Quirks can have a wide variety of features and abilities depending on the individual, but the common similarity seems to be 
>   that these Quirks are a part of the user's physicality, causing the user to exhibit irregular bodily features that generally have some sort of purpose to them. As a result, Mutant Quirks are passively active and, at a glance, are the most identifiable. [source](http://bokunoheroacademia.wikia.com/wiki/Quirk#Mutant)

Comment: A much more obvious example is Tsu! Her body has imbibed the physicality of a Frog